# How to kill multiple child process

Tags: c, kill-process

In C program simulating reader-writer problem, I have created multiple child processes using `fork()` and each child process called `execlp()` and runs another program (reader or writer) in an **xterm** window.

When I end the `main()`, those child running in xterm are still alive. How do i terminate them as well?

Code sample below-

```
main() {
    while(1) {
    scanf(choice);
    switch(choice) {
        case 1: 
            reader()
            break;
        case 2: 
            writer();
            break;
        default:
            kill(getpgid(getpid()), SIGTERM); // killing the group id
            return 0;
        }
    }

reader() {
    /*
    some semaphore manipulation
    */
    execlp("xterm", "xterm", "-e", "./read", NULL);
    /*
    some semaphore manipulation
    */
    return 0;
    }

writer() {
    /*
    some semaphore manipulation
    */
    execlp("xterm", "xterm", "-e", "./write", NULL);
    /*
    some semaphore manipulation
    */
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Group id of the parent and the child should be the same after forking so sending  `kill(pid,SIGTERM);`
should take care of them ( where pid is the group Id )

as pointed ouf by caf in a comment bellow ,  `kill(0, SIGTERM)` will send the signal to the current process's process group

Comment: how to determine the group id?

Comment: using getpgid() , more details are available here (http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpgid) hope that helps

Comment: I have done "kill(getpgid(getpid()),SIGTERM);" But the xterm windows are still open, and I can still continue to work on them.

Comment: what does your execlp () calls looks like ? (an easier solution would be to keep a list of your child IDs at creation in the parent, and later cicle thru it and kill each one.

Comment: also you might want to take at the first example here ( http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch24_22.htm ) and see how it applies to your case

Comment: `kill(pid, SIGTERM)` will send the signal to a single process with PID `pid`.  To send a signal to a process group, you need to use `kill(-pid, SIGTERM)`.  Alternatively you can use `kill(0, SIGTERM)` to send the signal to the current process's process group.

Comment: *palm slap* totally forgot abt kill (0,...) , I ll update my answers , thanks @caf